# Greedy Algorithm Number List

Tags: c++, list, algorithm, numbers, greedy

I am working at c++ and I need to find a greedy algorithm that given an array of positive integers, determines which pairs of summed even equal numbers have to the right of the array some odd number greater than that sum. Returning all possibilities. I have thought about creating a list of pair numbers and its position, so I could go from this position to the end. But these substructure gives me the answer, so it's not a greedy algorithm, adding that it's criteria is not correct. Can someone help me?

```
Example:
[4,5,9,4,0,11,6,6,8,8,91,73,7,69]

Output:
[4,4,11,91,73,69]
[6,6,91,73,69]
[8,8,11,91,73,69]
```

Thanks :)

Comment: If the input is `[2,2,5,2,7]`, what is the output?

Comment: Sorry, I got lost with "which pairs of summed even equal numbers have to the right of the array some odd number greater than that sum", can you separate that into shorter sentences or give some examples?

Comment: If the input is [2,2,5,2,7] the output is [2,2,5,7]

Comment: What I need is to find 2 equal-pair numbers and all it's odd numbers from the last pair to the end, that their sum (if the pair is 2,2 the sum will be 4) is smaller than them. Pair: 2,2 Next numbers: 2,4,8,9,7 Odd bigger numbers: 9,7

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not very tidy. I hope someone can elaborate this, if need be.

Suppose the largest number in the given array (call it A) is M. Create another array B[M+1][2] and init B[x][y]=-1. Traverse through A. If B[A[x]][0]==-1, make it x. If it is not -1 and B[A[x]][1]=-1, make B[A[x]][1] = x (Else, do not interfere). This way you can fill up B with the first two positions of every element x of A. This can be done in O(N).

```
Run a loop i through B : 
  if B[i][1] != -1 : 
    run a loop j though A from j=B[i][1]+1 :
      print if A[j] > 2*i and A[j] is odd
```

This second part can be done in O(N^2) which accounts to a total complexity (time) of O(N^2).